Finding Discounts for Multiple Items Accounting for Tax
I need a formula and/or a programmatic function (in any language) which will properly calculate a product discount so a customer can pay a price agreed upon at checkout, including tax, with multiple taxes applied to different amounts of the item price. The out-the-door price is not necessarily known until checkout and is kind of a bargaining tactic. For instance:

Customer wishes to buy multiple items with a subtotal of \$6,000
There is a 6% Sales Tax on all items
There is an additional 1% on the first \$5,000 of all items.




Item
Price
Quantity
Total
Amount Surtaxed
0.01 Surtax Amount
Pctg of Order Total




Thing 1
\$100.00
1
\$100.00
\$100.00
\$1.00
1.56%


Thing 2
\$5,500.00
1
\$5,500.00
\$5,000.00
\$50.00
85.74%


Thing 3
$400.00
1
\$400.00
\$400.00
\$4.00
6.24%













Subtotal
\$6,000.00







Base Sales Tax (6%)
\$360.00







County Surtax (1%)
\$55.00







Total Tax
\$415.00







Order Total
\$6,415.00






The customer wants to only pay \$6,000 so we agree on that amount. Our store needs to ensure that sales taxes are paid on the order but, of course, we don't want to pay those taxes. So, we want to discount each item to get to a new subtotal which when the taxes are applied our new Order Total is exactly \$6,000. The customer ends up paying the tax on lower priced items. (Note that there’s multiple ways to adjust prices; you can come up with your own criteria.)
We've come up with a couple formulas for this and it works fine when we're only worried about a singular tax rate or just a single item. When we need to handle multiple tax rates and multiple items, we have a hard time getting the correct total.
I can post what we've tried but I'm afraid that will muddy the waters. We call this an "out the door" price.

Reduce the price of every item by one percent until the out the door price
(Order) becomes $6000,.$ The result is somewhere between the last two lines:
\begin{align}
Price1 &&   Price2 &&   Price3 &&      Order\
100.00 &&  5500.00 &&   400.00 &&  6415.00\
98.01 &&  5390.55 &&   392.04 &&  6288.34\
97.03 &&  5336.64 &&   388.12 &&  6225.95\
96.06 &&  5283.28 &&   384.24 &&  6164.19\
95.10 &&  5230.45 &&   380.40 &&  6103.05\
94.15 &&  5178.14 &&   376.59 &&  6042.52\
93.21 &&  5126.36 &&   372.83 &&  5982.60\
\end{align}

I don’t understand why this question is closed. This is a very good question—well-formulated and well-motivated, and definitely not “opinion-based.” Can someone explain why the question is closed, and how to improve it?

Maybe OP can try to re-post it to Economics SE?

@SteveNorkus OP is happy and was helped. If another SE wants to continue with an open ended discussion of this. Fine.

@KurtG. Yes, I'm happy with the answer SteveNorkus provided but I am not happy that someone (you?) closed my question for absolutely no reason.

@JoeDavis closing a question needs five votes. I confess that I was one of them :) Nonetheless you are welcome to vote to reopen mentioning why you think this needs further contributions.

@KurtG. I guess I just don't understand why it was closed. The given reason provides zero explanation. Saying the question is "opinion-based" is merely your opinion if you don't give a reason why it is opinion-based.

I did in fact like your question as a well-formed example of what many of the students struggling with their homework here will face once they take a job in the industry. From experience I can assure you that they will wish their client explains the problem so well as you did here. Rather than taking the closure too personal please be encouraged to post more of that sort. Now to your question: my personal reason to vote for closure that was that I saw that the problem could quickly be solved in a practical way and does not really warrant an open ended discussion.

(I just upvoted the question and @SteveNorkus' answer.)

Suppose that there are $n$ commodities, labeled with integers $1,\cdots,n$. Denote the price vector of the commodities as $\boldsymbol p=(p_1,\cdots,p_n)$. For a given consumption bundle $\boldsymbol x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, where $x_i$ is the amount of commodity $i$ purchased, the total expenditure is
$$
W=\boldsymbol p\cdot\boldsymbol x+t(\boldsymbol p,\boldsymbol x),
$$
where $t(\boldsymbol p,\boldsymbol x)$ is the amount of tax payed for purchasing the bundle $\boldsymbol x$ at price $\boldsymbol p$ (we make no assumptions about the function $t$, other than that it is continuous and monotonically increasing w.r.t. $p_i$ and $x_i$ for all $i$).
We want to adjust the price $\boldsymbol p$ to $\boldsymbol p^*$ such that the total expediture equals an agreed-upon amount $W^*$:
$$
W^*=\boldsymbol p^*\cdot \boldsymbol x+t(\boldsymbol p^*,\boldsymbol x).
$$
Note that the solution is, in general, not unique. However, we can impose the restriction that
$$
\boldsymbol p^*=\lambda\boldsymbol p
$$
where $\lambda$ is the “discount rate”. Fixing $\boldsymbol p$ and $\boldsymbol x$, we can express the expenditure as a function of $\lambda$:
$$
W(\lambda)=\lambda\boldsymbol p\cdot \boldsymbol x+t(\lambda\boldsymbol p,\boldsymbol x).
$$
Note that $W(\lambda)$ is strictly increasing w.r.t. $\lambda$. Therefore if $W(0)<W^*<W(1)$ then there exists a unique solution $0<\lambda^*<1$. Now you can use any root-finding algorithm to obtain the value of $\lambda^*$.

Edit: Here's a simple Python program I wrote to solve the problem in your question:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def tax(price, consumption):
    surtax_amount = np.minimum(price * consumption, 5000)
    return 0.06 * np.dot(price, consumption) + 0.01 * np.sum(surtax_amount)

def adjust_price(initial_price, consumption, adjusted_expenditure):
    excess_expenditure = lambda c: c * np.dot(initial_price, consumption) + tax(c * initial_price, consumption) - adjusted_expenditure
    discount_rate = fsolve(excess_expenditure, [0.75])[0]
    return discount_rate, initial_price * discount_rate

p = np.array([100.00, 5500.00, 400.00])
x = np.array([1, 1, 1])
r, p0 = adjust_price(p, x, 6000)
print(f"{100 * (1 - r):.2f}% discount, adjusted price vector is {p0}")

Output:
6.52% discount, adjusted price vector is [  93.47996858 5141.3982718   373.91987431]


this solved my problem perfectly. Thank you!
